# Get name of struct field using reflection

Tags: go

What is the way of printing "Foo" here? In this example, what prints is "string".

http://play.golang.org/p/ZnK6PRwEPp

```
type A struct {
    Foo string
}

func (a *A) PrintFoo() {
    fmt.Println("Foo value is " + a.Foo)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "afoo"}
    val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a))
    fmt.Println(val.Field(0).Type().Name())
}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You want `val.Type().Field(0).Name`.  The `Field` method on `reflect.Type` will return a struct describing that field, which includes the name, among other information.

There is no way to retrieve the field name for a `reflect.Value` representing a particular field value, since that is a property of the containing struct.

Comment: "There is no way to retrieve the field name for a reflect.Value representing a particular field value" - Why is that the case? Isn't the type and name part of the field itself?

Comment: @sat As soon as you have the `reflect.Value` of a specific field, it is no different to any other variable. Only the struct has the information about it's fields.

Comment: @sat: in your example, `val.Field(0)` is no different to a `reflect.Value` for any other string.  It doesn't "remember" that it was part of a struct.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge - But I don't really need it to remember that it belongs to a struct. All I was trying to print was the name of the variable from the field itself using reflection (whether its part of a struct or not). Sorry if its really a newbie question

Comment: That's the thing: the variable doesn't have a name -- its just a location in memory.

Comment: So the struct maintains meta information for the name? But a simple variable has none?

Comment: The runtime type information for struct types includes the names and types of its members, yes.

Comment: Also note that there is no in-memory pointer from the variable `a` to the type `*A`: that is static information.  The way the reflect package works is that calling `reflect.ValueOf(a)` involves creating an interface variable holding the `a`.  This variable will use `a`'s static type, and that is what is used to do the introspection.

Answer (score 43):

I think the better way to get the fields' name in the struct is

```
func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "afoo"}
    val := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    for i:=0; i<val.NumField();i++{
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Name)
    }
}
```

There are two tips:

1. use `.Elem()` after you `reflect.ValueOf(a)`, because in your case, a is a pointer.
2. `val.Field(i).Type().Name` is totally different from `val.Type().Field(i).Name`. The latter one can get the name of the field in the struct

Hope that it is helpful..

If you want to have a look at more cases, please check [my 2mins article](https://oscarchou.com/posts/golang/reflect-all/)

Answer (score 32):

You need to Get the Field of the Type Definition not of the Value.

http://play.golang.org/p/7Bc7MJikbJ

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type A struct {
    Foo string
}

func (a *A) PrintFoo() {
    fmt.Println("Foo value is " + a.Foo)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "afoo"}
    val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(a))
    fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(0).Name)
}
```

Comment: Nice example but your answer lacks an explanation.

Answer (score 29):

**Note that this solution references a Go module which is now deprecated, and is no longer being maintained. It was deprecated as of *Oct 11, 2018*.**

With the new `Names` method of the [structs](https://github.com/fatih/structs) package it's even easier:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type A struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
}

func main() {
    names := structs.Names(&A{})
    fmt.Println(names) // ["Foo", "Bar"]
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention that it's your own package.

Comment: @swdon When Fatih Arslan build a lib it's almost as it was the standard library.

Comment: Mention that's my own package? The package name itself already has my name, I'm not sure how else I can tell that :)

Comment: this package is no longer maintained

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type A struct {
    Foo string
}

func (a *A) PrintFoo() {
    fmt.Println("Foo value is " + a.Foo)
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "afoo"}

    //long and bored code
    t := reflect.TypeOf(*a)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            fmt.Println(t.Field(i).Name)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not a stuct")
    }

    //shorthanded call
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(*a).Field(0).Name)//can panic if no field exists

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function, which takes the `struct` as the first parameter, and then its `fields`. It returns the `map` type, which is convenient to use

If you use fields from another structure, nothing will happen

If you try to use a `different type`, it will cause `panic`

Note that the field has an ordinal number according to the list (starting from 0). All fields in the structure must start with `uppercase`

```
func GetStructFieldName(Struct interface{}, StructField ...interface{}) (fields map[int]string) {
    fields = make(map[int]string)
    s := reflect.ValueOf(Struct).Elem()

    for r := range StructField {
        f := reflect.ValueOf(StructField[r]).Elem()

        for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
            valueField := s.Field(i)
            if valueField.Addr().Interface() == f.Addr().Interface() {
                fields[i] = s.Type().Field(i).Name
            }
        }
    }
    return fields
}
```

Full example and [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VMm1BvG6vNV)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Example struct {
    Apple bool
    Pear  int
}

func GetStructFieldName(Struct interface{}, StructField ...interface{}) (fields map[int]string) {
    fields = make(map[int]string)

    for r := range StructField {
        s := reflect.ValueOf(Struct).Elem()
        f := reflect.ValueOf(StructField[r]).Elem()

        for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
            valueField := s.Field(i)
            if valueField.Addr().Interface() == f.Addr().Interface() {
                fields[i] = s.Type().Field(i).Name
            }
        }
    }
    return fields
}

func main() {
    e := Example{}

    names := GetStructFieldName(&e, &e.Apple, &e.Pear)

    fmt.Println(names)
    fmt.Println(names[0], names[1])

    for i := range names {
        fmt.Println(names[i])
    }

    /* Output:
    map[0:Apple 1:Pear]
    Apple Pear
    Apple
    Pear
    */
}
```

Comment: Some day I should really start with throwing money at people who write answers like you do. This is exactly what I was looking for! 

Answer (score 2):

You can also use https://github.com/fatih/structs

```
// Convert the fields of a struct to a []*Field
fields := s.Fields()

for _, f := range fields {
    fmt.Printf("field name: %+v\n", f.Name())
}
```